# Janus WebRTC installation issue?

Tags: compilation, debian, beagleboneblack, janus-gateway

I am installing Janus WebRTC on Beaglebone Black(BBB).
I execute the `janus_config.sh` script file below to set environment variables:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -gt 1 ] || [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Usage: source /path/to/this/build_script.sh path/where/dependencies/built"
fi

JANUS_PATH=$1

if ! [ -d $JANUS_PATH ]; then
    mkdir -v $JANUS_PATH
fi

BUILD==$(./config.guess) 

unset JANUS_CFLAGS
JANUS_CFLAGS+="-I$1/include/glib-2.0 "
JANUS_CFLAGS+="-I$1/lib/glib-2.0/include "
JANUS_CFLAGS+="-I$1/include "
JANUS_CFLAGS+="-I$1/include/gio-unix-2.0/gio "
JANUS_CFLAGS+="-I$1/include/nice "
JANUS_CFLAGS+="-I/home/debian/usr/local/include/openssl "
JANUS_CFLAGS+="-I$1/include/opus "
JANUS_CFLAGS+="-I$1/include/sofia-sip-1.12/sofia-resolv "
JANUS_CFLAGS+="-I$1/include/srtp "
JANUS_CFLAGS+="-I$1/include/stun "
JANUS_CFLAGS+="-I$1/include/stun/usages "
JANUS_CFLAGS+="-I$1/lib/libffi-3.2.1/include "
export JANUS_CFLAGS

unset JANUS_LIBS
JANUS_LIBS+="-L$1/lib -lglib-2.0 "
JANUS_LIBS+="-L/home/debian/usr/local/lib -lssl -lcrypto "
JANUS_LIBS+="-L$1/lib -lsrtp -lcrypto "
JANUS_LIBS+="-L$1/lib -lusrsctp"
export JANUS_LIBS

unset LDFLAGS
LDFLAGS+="-L$1/lib "
LDFLAGS+="-L/home/debian/usr/local/lib"
export LDFLAGS

unset LIBS
LIBS+="-lsrtp -lcrypto -lusrsctp -lglib-2.0 -lnice -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lsofia-sip-ua -ljansson -lssl -lgmodule-2.0 "
LIBS+="-lffi -lgthread-2.0 -lz "
export LIBS

unset CPPFLAGS
CPPFLAGS+="-I$1/include "
CPPFLAGS+="-I$1/include/glib-2.0 "
CPPFLAGS+="-I$1/lib/glib-2.0/include "
CPPFLAGS+="-pthread -I$1/include/nice "
CPPFLAGS+="-I$1/include/sofia-sip-1.12"
export CPPFLAGS

unset TRANSPORTS_CFLAGS
TRANSPORTS_CFLAGS+="-I$1/include/glib-2.0 "
TRANSPORTS_CFLAGS+="-I$1/lib/glib-2.0/include "
TRANSPORTS_CFLAGS+="-I$1/include"
export TRANSPORTS_CFLAGS

unset TRANSPORTS_LIBS
TRANSPORTS_LIBS+="-L$1/lib -lglib-2.0 "
TRANSPORTS_LIBS+="-L/home/debian/usr/local/lib -lssl -lcrypto "
TRANSPORTS_LIBS+="-L$1/lib -lsrtp -lcrypto "
TRANSPORTS_LIBS+="-L$1/lib -lusrsctp"
export TRANSPORTS_LIBS

unset PLUGINS_CFLAGS
unset PLUGINS_LIBS
PLUGINS_CFLAGS=$JANUS_CFLAGS
PLUGINS_LIBS=$JANUS_LIBS    
export PLUGINS_CFLAGS
export PLUGINS_LIBS


./configure --build=$BUILD  --disable-plugin-voicemail --disable-plugin-videoroom --disable-plugin-videocall --disable-plugin-recordplay --disable-plugin-echotest --disable-plugin-audiobridge --disable-websockets --disable-rabbitmq --disable-plugin-sip --disable-docs --prefix=$JANUS_PATH
```

When  run command `source janus_config.sh $PREFIX`,I get error, see config.log below for more detail:

```
/*
    $ ./configure --build==armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf --disable-plugin-voicemail --disable-plugin-videoroom --disable-plugin-videocall --disable-plugin-recordplay --disable-plugin-echotest --disable-plugin-audiobridge --disable-websockets --disable-rabbitmq --disable-plugin-sip --disable-docs --prefix=/home/debian/Janus/usr


    ## --------- ##
    ## Platform. ##
    ## --------- ##

    hostname = beaglebone
    uname -m = armv7l
    uname -r = 3.8.13-bone70
    uname -s = Linux
    uname -v = #1 SMP Fri Jan 23 02:15:42 UTC 2015

    /usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
    /bin/uname -X     = unknown

    /bin/arch              = unknown
    /usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
    /usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
    /usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
    /bin/machine           = unknown
    /usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
    /bin/universe          = unknown

    PATH: /home/debian/bin
    PATH: /home/debian/.linuxbrew/bin
    PATH: /usr/local/sbin
    PATH: /usr/local/bin
    PATH: /usr/sbin
    PATH: /usr/bin
    PATH: /sbin
    PATH: /bin
    PATH: /usr/local/games
    PATH: /usr/games


    ## ----------- ##
    ## Core tests. ##
    ## ----------- ##

    configure:2466: checking for a BSD-compatible install
    configure:2534: result: /usr/bin/install -c
    configure:2545: checking whether build environment is sane
    configure:2600: result: yes
    configure:2751: checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p
    configure:2790: result: /bin/mkdir -p
    configure:2797: checking for gawk
    configure:2827: result: no
    configure:2797: checking for mawk
    configure:2813: found /usr/bin/mawk
    configure:2824: result: mawk
    configure:2835: checking whether make sets $(MAKE)
    configure:2857: result: yes
    configure:2886: checking whether make supports nested variables
    configure:2903: result: yes
    configure:3040: checking whether make supports nested variables
    configure:3057: result: yes
    configure:3081: checking for style of include used by make
    configure:3109: result: GNU
    configure:3180: checking for gcc
    configure:3196: found /usr/bin/gcc
    configure:3207: result: gcc
    configure:3436: checking for C compiler version
    configure:3445: gcc --version >&5
    gcc (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2
    Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
    This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
    warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

    configure:3456: $? = 0
    configure:3445: gcc -v >&5
    Using built-in specs.
    COLLECT_GCC=gcc
    COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/lto-wrapper
    Target: arm-linux-gnueabihf
    Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Debian 4.9.2-10' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.9/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.9 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.9 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libitm --disable-libquadmath --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.9-armhf/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.9-armhf --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.9-armhf --with-arch-directory=arm --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-arch=armv7-a --with-fpu=vfpv3-d16 --with-float=hard --with-mode=thumb --enable-checking=release --build=arm-linux-gnueabihf --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf --target=arm-linux-gnueabihf
    Thread model: posix
    gcc version 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-10) 
    configure:3456: $? = 0
    configure:3445: gcc -V >&5
    gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
    gcc: fatal error: no input files
    compilation terminated.
    configure:3456: $? = 4
    configure:3445: gcc -qversion >&5
    gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'
    gcc: fatal error: no input files
    compilation terminated.
    configure:3456: $? = 4
    configure:3476: checking whether the C compiler works
    configure:3498: gcc  -I/home/debian/Janus/usr/include -I/home/debian/Janus/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/home/debian/Janus/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -pthread -I/home/debian/Janus/usr/include/nice -I/home/debian/Janus/usr/include/sofia-sip-1.12 -L/home/debian/Janus/usr/lib -L/home/debian/usr/local/lib conftest.c -lsrtp -lcrypto -lusrsctp -lglib-2.0 -lnice -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lsofia-sip-ua -ljansson -lssl -lgmodule-2.0 -lffi -lgthread-2.0 -lz  >&5
```

## I think problem is here because openssl directory is not as I set in janus_config.sh, I install openssl in /home/debian/usr/local

```
    /home/debian/Janus/usr/lib/libcrypto.a(mem_clr.o): In function `OPENSSL_cleanse':
    mem_clr.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `OPENSSL_cleanse'
    /home/debian/Janus/usr/lib/libcrypto.a(armv4cpuid.o):(.text+0x1c): first defined here
    /home/debian/Janus/usr/lib/libcrypto.a(armcap.o): In function `OPENSSL_cpuid_setup':
    armcap.c:(.text.startup+0x0): multiple definition of `OPENSSL_cpuid_setup'
    /home/debian/Janus/usr/lib/libcrypto.a(cryptlib.o):cryptlib.c:(.text+0x8d8): first defined here
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    configure:3502: $? = 1
    configure:3540: result: no
    configure: failed program was:
    | /* confdefs.h */
    | #define PACKAGE_NAME "Janus Gateway"
    | #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "janus-gateway"
    | #define PACKAGE_VERSION "0.1.0"
    | #define PACKAGE_STRING "Janus Gateway 0.1.0"
    | #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "https://github.com/meetecho/janus-gateway"
    | #define PACKAGE_URL "https://janus.conf.meetecho.com"
    | #define PACKAGE "janus-gateway"
    | #define VERSION "0.1.0"
    | /* end confdefs.h.  */
    | 
    | int
    | main ()
    | {
    | 
    |   ;
    |   return 0;
    | }
    configure:3545: error: in `/home/debian/Janus/Dependencies/janus-gateway-master':
    configure:3547: error: C compiler cannot create executables
    See `config.log' for more details;
*/
```

Could you help me find out the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Multiples definitions for the same resource, problably, how did you configure it??? try this:

./config -fPIC -DOPENSSL_PIC